# How to Authorize Myself with Twitter OAuth 1.0 on Scala

Tags: scala, twitter, oauth

I tried `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=1&user_id=XXX` on Scala, but I got an error `401 Authorization required`.

Here's my spec:

- macOS Sierra 10.12.2
- Scala 2.12.1
- sbt 0.13.13

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "hoge"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.0-M2",
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.3.0"
)
```

And `hoge.scala`:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import java.net.URLEncoder
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import javax.crypto.Mac
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

object Hoge {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val consumerKey = "AAA"
    val consumerSecret = "BBB"
    val token = "CCC"
    val tokenSecret = "DDD"
    val timestamp = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString
    val nonce = System.nanoTime.toString
    val id = "XXX"

    val host = "https://api.twitter.com"
    val path = "/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"
    val url = host + path

    val query = Map(
      "count" -> "1",
      "user_id" -> id
    )

    val sign = signature(
      url, consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, tokenSecret, timestamp, nonce, query
    )
    val header = Map(
      "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      "Authorization" -> oauthHeader(consumerKey, token, sign, timestamp, nonce)
    )

    val ws = NingWSClient()
    val res = get(ws)(url, query, header)
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    res.value.get.get.json
    ws.close()
  }

  def signature(url: String, consumerKey: String, consumerSecret: String, token: String, tokenSecret: String, timestamp: String, nonce: String, query: Map[String, String]) = {
    val params = Map(
      "oauth_consumer_key" -> consumerKey,
      "oauth_nonce" -> nonce,
      "oauth_signature_method" -> "HMAC-SHA1",
      "oauth_timestamp" -> timestamp,
      "oauth_token" -> token,
      "oauth_version" -> "1.0"
    ) ++ query
    val paramsEncoded = params.toList.sorted map { case (k, v) => urlencode(k) + "=" + urlencode(v) }
    val paramString = paramsEncoded mkString "&"
    val signatureBase = "GET&" + urlencode(url) + "&" + urlencode(paramString)
    val signingKey = urlencode(consumerSecret) + "&" + urlencode(tokenSecret)
    base64encode(encry(signingKey, signatureBase))
  }

  def oauthHeader(consumerKey: String, token: String, sign: String, timestamp: String, nonce: String) = {
    val params = Map(
      "oauth_consumer_key" -> consumerKey,
      "oauth_nonce" -> nonce,
      "oauth_signature" -> sign,
      "oauth_signature_method" -> "HMAC-SHA1",
      "oauth_timestamp" -> timestamp,
      "oauth_token" -> token,
      "oauth_version" -> "1.0"
    ).toList.sorted
    "OAuth " + (params map { case (k, v) => urlencode(k) + "=\"" + urlencode(v) + "\"" } mkString ", ")
  }

  def urlencode(s: String) = {
    URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8")
  }

  def base64encode(s: String) = {
    Base64.encodeBase64String(s.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  }

  def encry(key: String, data: String) = {
    val secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes, "HmacSHA1")
    val mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1")
    mac.init(secret)
    val res = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    res map { r => "%02x".format(r) } mkString ""
  }

  def get(ws: NingWSClient)(url: String, query: Map[String, String], header: Map[String, String]) = {
    ws.url(url).withQueryString(query.toList: _*).withHeaders(header.toList: _*).get
  }
}
```

`timestamp`, `nonce`, `sign` and `oauthHeader` in this case are

```
timestamp = 1482542041
nonce = 214129951907166
sign = YWQ2Y2VjNzJkOTQwY2JhYjEzYzgxZDM2YTg3ZGNlNjQ3ZjIzMDQ4Yw==
oauthHeader = OAuth oauth_consumer_key="AAA", oauth_nonce="214129951907166", oauth_signature="YWQ2Y2VjNzJkOTQwY2JhYjEzYzgxZDM2YTg3ZGNlNjQ3ZjIzMDQ4Yw%3D%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1482542041", oauth_token="CCC", oauth_version="1.0"
```

I did `sbt compile` and then `sbt run`, and got a response `401 Authorization required`.

I think there be no problem between `val ws = NingWSClient()` and `ws.close()`: when I sent GET/POST requests which do not need OAuth 1.0 (e.g. Google API), I succeeded.

I also think the consumer key, consumer secret, token, token secret are correct: when I ran a similar process on Ruby, everything was OK.

And I think the process to make a signature is correct, for I checked it in Documentation over and over.

So, I think encoding or encrypting them was wrong.
I do not want to use libraries Twitter4J because I am just studying Scala.

Please tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URLEncoder.encode` makes a space into '+' not '%20', so put `replace("+", "%20")`.
Encrypting becomes:

```
val hmacShai = "HmacSHA1"
val keyStr = new SecretKeySpec(bytes(key), hmacShai)
val sig = {
  val mac = Mac.getInstance(hmacShai)
  mac.init(keyStr)
  new String(base64encode(mac.doFinal(bytes(data))))
}
```